# onNext triggered for each element of ArrayList instead of triggering once using RXJava

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I have an `ArrayList` of type `Object` that I'm listening to using an `Observable` pattern:

```
//Instances 
private List<Store> storeList = new ArrayList<>();
private static PublishSubject<List<Store>> publishStoreListSubject = PublishSubject.create();

private Observer<List<Store>> storeListObserver = new Observer<List<Store>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) { }

    @Override
    public void onNext(List<Store> storeList) {
        //Do work ....
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) { }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() { }
};
```

in my **onCreate** method:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        publishStoreListSubject.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(storeListObserver);

}
```

In my **client side server** method, I have the following:

```
onRetrieveStores() {
  publishStoreListSubject.onNext(storeList);
  ..
  ..
  ..
}
```

**PROBLEM:** The onNext is being triggered for each item instead of for the whole storeList as one unit. For example: if I have 4 stores, the onNext is being triggered 4 times.

Btw, I do not have any mechanisms that is looping through in my onRetrieveStores

Comment: do you have multiple instances calling `onNext` to your member (static) `PublishSubject`?

Comment: No, it is only called from the onRetrieveStores() method. That the only time I'm calling onNext.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do some action on when last item has been emitted then you should implement onComplete(). onNext() is called for each new item emitted.

Comment: It is partially working when using onComplete instead of onNext. For example, if the retrieval happens the first time, then everything works fine. Let's say after that, there is a new store that gets added to the list of stores, and onRetrieveStores() is triggered again, then the observer storeListObserver will not trigger. I debugged-walked into the code, and noticed that inside onComplete, subscribers.get() == TERMINATED) is true. That might be the issue why it's not triggering again.

Comment: When a change in store happens to the list (whether it's a removal or an addition), I'm clearing my Object arraylist, and triggering onRetrieveStores again. At this point, I'm trying to have my onComplete re-execute and not only execute once for all.